# is it ok to instantiate lists in my domain object's constructor when using nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, list, fluent-nhibernate, constructor

i have an object that have many properties that are lists.  to avoid having to do null checks everywhere before i call Add, Count, Clear, etc  . . . i thought it would be better to new up all the lists upfront

so inside by Resource object in this case, i have the following code:

```
    public Resource()
    {
        Regions = new List<Region>();
        Directs = new List<Direct>();
    }

   public virtual IList<Direct> Directs { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<Region> Region{ get; set; }
```

i do get the warning in Visual Studio saying **calling virtual methods in the constructor**

is there anything wrong or any risk to the code above when using nhibernate ?? if it is wrong, is there a better way of achieving this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine. But if you want a cleaner approach, use:

```
public Resource()
{
    _Regions = new List<Region>();
    _Directs = new List<Direct>();
}

IList<Direct> _Directs;
public virtual IList<Direct> Directs { get { return _Directs; } }

IList<Region> _Regions;
public virtual IList<Region> Regions { get { return _Regions; } }
```

And map with `access="nosetter.pascalcase-underscore"` (if you use my naming convention; check the tables at http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property for other alternatives)

Comment: i dont understand the lack of a setter here.  How is nhibernate going to set the property??

Comment: Using the field; that's why I specified an access strategy. Please read the link.

Comment: I wondered what the access setter was all about, I now understand... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with it. The warning is only there because the properties could be overridden in a derived class as far as I know. But yeah, no problem instantiating in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The collection needs to be instantiated before you can add a member to it, so it's best to always instantiate collections in the constructor.